# Lenovo Yoga 700 Wifi issues

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, lenovo

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my new Lenovo Yoga 700 (model 80QD). I got it working from command line, and i'm currently using my WiFi to write this, however, the Connection Manager does not let me configure the WiFi through the UI.

First issue: the firmware files /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode and /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode were missing (driver error message on dmesg). I downloaded them from https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware , as i could not find an ubuntu package with these two files.

Second issue: network manager refuses to manage this wifi device. This first symptom looked like the WiFi "switch" widget on the network menu on the top right of the unity window manager was off. Trying to switch it on, caused it to animated back and forth. Currently, after all my games, the wifi looks greyed out.

I've run the WiFi info script, attached below. Its clear that the rfkill command sees a "Hardware Block". Now first: i don't have a hardware rf kill switch on this laptop (User manual: https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/yoga_700-14isk_ug_en_201509.pdf ). Second, i'm currently using the wifi, just configured from command line. This can also be seen below, as the wifi is associated successfully (i used wpa_supplicant). And third, it also claims the bluetooth is hardware blocked, but i'm also using my bluetooth earphones while writing this, and i've configured them using the Ubuntu UI, which worked great.

I've also noticed:

```
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
```

below on the network manager info for this device, but i'm less familiar with what this actually means.

Thank you, would love except fixing this issue for the long term, if you could conjure a short term hack. Otherwise i'll have to keep configuring WiFi from the command line, which is quite annoying.

Edit 2: As requested, here is the steps i performed to connect to my home wireless:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up
wpa_passphrase shlompiya <password> > /tmp/conf
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlp1s0 -c/tmp/conf
sudo dhclient wlp1s0
sudo sh -c 'echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf'
```

Regarding to airplane mode: i forgot to mention i played with it, apologies. Airplane mode changed the software blocked settings when invoking `rfkill list`

I've managed to ugly hack it: i've recompiled the network-manager package, and made it ignore the "hardware blocked" rfkill mode completely. After this hack, i now have the UI working (but most likely i broke the software rf kill switch functionality). This will work for me for now, lets try to fix this for the next guy ;-)

recompilation and patch went something like this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager
mkdir ~/laptop
cd ~/latop
apt-get source network-manager
cd network-manager-1.0.4
vim src/nm-rfkill-manager.c
line 168:
      return RFKILL_HARD_BLOCKED;
replace
//      return RFKILL_HARD_BLOCKED;
// PASH PATCH
nm_log_warn (LOGD_RFKILL, "PASH PATCH: overrided hardware killswitch state to not killed");
return RFKILL_UNBLOCKED;
```

End of edit 2

Wifi info script, followed by network-manager logs attached here below: Edit: due to character count limitation on question length, i edited out blocks about virtual bridges (belong to libvirt, AFAIK).

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Nov 2015 12:21 IST +0200

Booted last: 24 Nov 2015 00:00 IST +0200

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-19-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 11 11:39:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, nomdmonddf, nomdmonisw

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3166] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. RDF8
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f3:206f Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:077b Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. RDF8
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c43 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                294912  0
mac80211              733184  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              548864  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    20480  0
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  36864  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1062755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:616313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1411090961 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:74460235 (74.4 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"shlompiya"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:145   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp1s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       889     1  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.2.0-19-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               15.195093.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=shlompiya
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jerusalem (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

virbr0-nic  no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.805 GHz

wlp1s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'GadiB' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"GadiB"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003503a7e68d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"shlompiya"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001a2720f7747
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'Shlomo' [AC3]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Shlomo"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000020699bbc02a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'GadiBr-5G' [AC4]>
                    Channel:161
                    Frequency:5.805 GHz
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"GadiBr-5G"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005ec63c7df6
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     3BBD88D7E8252B90136F463
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        36:C9:DD:EE:C2:96:8B:FC:DA:67:40:D7:CD:68:4B:F0:4B:70:27:94
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-19-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     065F4A11FE84275F51A59F2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        36:C9:DD:EE:C2:96:8B:FC:DA:67:40:D7:CD:68:4B:F0:4B:70:27:94
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     71898921ACA21BC032CBB65
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        36:C9:DD:EE:C2:96:8B:FC:DA:67:40:D7:CD:68:4B:F0:4B:70:27:94
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-19-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     1F1A25B2E9C847110BD9ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        36:C9:DD:EE:C2:96:8B:FC:DA:67:40:D7:CD:68:4B:F0:4B:70:27:94
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[   49.302429] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   49.378908] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   52.855282] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]>
[   52.859911] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[   52.861820] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   52.864792] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[   52.869807] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   52.871332] wlp1s0: associated
[   52.871393] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[10305.572331] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[10315.090480] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[10315.180702] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[10318.516315] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]>
[10318.519522] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[10318.522330] wlp1s0: authenticated
[10318.525645] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[10318.529169] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[10318.538274] wlp1s0: associated
[10318.538513] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[10367.559094] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[10372.804169] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[10372.879828] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[10376.366396] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]>
[10376.370441] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[10376.373547] wlp1s0: authenticated
[10376.373724] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (try 1/3)
[10376.377247] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'shlompiya' [AC2]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[10376.378461] wlp1s0: associated
[10376.378561] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

also, attaching `systemctl status network-manager -n 1000 -l` . If i understand the logging messages correctly, it indeed detects the hardware rf kill, and you can also see the switch to "unavailable" mode, which i don't understand what the reason 'managed' means. Edit: this had to be shortened due to character limitation on question length.

```
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  rfkill3: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver iwlwifi)
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform driver ideapad_acpi)
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanFactory (internal)
....
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  WiFi disabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  Networking is enabled by state file
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (wlp1s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (wlp1s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (wlp1s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (carrier: UNKNOWN, driver: 'iwlwifi', ifindex: 2)
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (wlp1s0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (lo): link connected
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  (lo): new Generic device (carrier: ON, driver: 'unknown', ifindex: 1)
נוב 24 09:24:53 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  startup complete
.....
נוב 24 09:25:03 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  WiFi hardware radio set enabled
נוב 24 09:25:03 shlompad NetworkManager[889]: <info>  WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include to process to start the wireless from the command line. Also, you laptop does have a kill switch. It is called 'Airplane Mode.' Airplane Mode:on is the same as Wireless Radio:off. As you manipulate the Airplane Mode switch, is there any change in: `rfkill list all`?

Comment: done.  like i edited, the airplane button only changed the software blocked in rfkill, and apologies for forgetting to mention it. Also, i've hacked myself a solution: i've recompiled network-manager to ignore hardware rfkill switch completly, and now my WiFi UI is working well (hack detailed in edit). So personally i'm set, but i will help with what i can to fix this correctly for the next guy.

Comment: digging a bit more in sysfs, i found `cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/name` says
ideapad_wlan . From the network manager source code, it seems that it has "slots" for rf kill switches, and this one registers into the "WiFi" slot, completely disabling wifi (so it's not the iwlwifi drivers fault at all). searching for this driver on google turns out this is the most common issue with it, and some suggest blacklisting it (though it contains more functionality). I therefore think maybe i should contact the driver maintainer? What do you think?

Comment: Certainly. Please register and file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Comment: done. link for future reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021

Comment: This is not a bug report. You just posted in other bug reports. It will not help to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Future seekers of help:

The fault seems to be with a buggy ideapad_laptop driver, which is not a unique issue to this laptop / model.

in order to get around issue #2, one possible solution is to just blacklist the driver, as suggested here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Wifi-is-hardware-disabled/td-p/1307405

Don't forget to solve #1 you'll need to download the new firmware:
https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware

For future reference: here is a link to the bug on a different model on lunchpad, i've added a comment about this specific model so it can be added to the driver. If this reproduces on OTHER MODELS, run dmidecode and check if you machine model is in the list inside the driver `drivers/platform/x86/ideapad_laptop.c` (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021)

Comment: You need to file a NEW bug report.

Comment: Done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1519900